# Creating variable names based on other variables

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to create variable names, based on another variable in a loop. How would I go about doing something like this?

```
y = a changing integer
for x in range(0, y):
    x += 1
    var(x) = something[x]
print var1
print var2
```

Comment: You don't. You probably want to create a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember having this very same question when I first started learning Python.  The short answer is that you shouldn't do it because it's a bad idea.  It clogs up namespaces, makes code harder to debug, and much harder for people to read.  Use a dictionary instead:

```
y = a changing integer
x = 0
var = {}
for x in range(0, y):
    x += 1
    var[x] = something[x]
```

Comment: You can actually do this.

Comment: yes, using globals, which are not recommended for code of any complexity

Comment: True, +1 for recommending dict. And advising against it. Globals definitely not necessary here

Comment: very tempting to use them anyway, though! :P

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `globals` as one way to dynamically create variables

e.g. for globals -

```
>>> for i in range(10):

...     globals()['number_%d' % i] = i

>>> print(globals())

>>> {'__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, 'number_3': 3, 
 'number_9': 9, 'number_1': 1, 'number_7': 7, 'number_4': 4, 'number_6': 6, 
 'number_0': 0, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, 'number_8': 8, 'number_5': 5, 
 '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'i': 9, 
 '__spec__': None, 'number_2': 2}
```

You could use your condition to specify how these are assigned.

But for what you need this sounds and usually always is unnecessary. A `tuple`, `list` even a `dict` as suggested in the other answer would be better.

Comment: I don't think that `locals()` will work here. It must be `globals()`.